# Print foreach value of array in one row

Tags: php, arrays

I have a following code

```
foreach($arr['transactions'] as $a){

    foreach($a as $key => $value){



    echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";


    }
}
```

Which gives output in one column.

Now what I want is print these values like below

416990962 COMPLETED Business Send 0183366139 0183366139 -1 0 0 655.99

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: This is fairly simple? Move the `<tr> </tr>` outside of the second foreach, so the `<tr> </tr>`  is only looped by the first loop.

Comment: Do you want to show all the values in a single row itself?

Comment: I`m guessing you have different columns in $value need so you need to split it.

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/atkGnHvG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 foreach($arr['transactions'] as $a){
    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($a as $key => $value){
           echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
       }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting result in one column because you are using `<tr>` inside the second loop. you need to use `<tr>` outside the second loop as:

```
<?php
foreach($arr['transactions'] as $a)
{
?>
    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($a as $key => $value)
        {
        ?>
            <td><?php echo $value;?></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:-

```
echo '<tr>';
foreach($a as $key => $value){
 echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
}
echo '</tr>';
```